# Recommended account manager for unix box?

Tags: web-hosting, imap, cyrus

I'm just getting into domain/website/IT hosting for a very small company. I've hosted their web server on an ec2 fedora server, where I also host a number of other domains.

I also have a cyrus imapd service that I use for my own use. They would like to start using something like that (well, they want me to host their email server - whatever that is). I'd like to give them imap accounts, and I'd also like to allow them to add/remove imap users.

Any suggestions as far as web interfaces, faqs, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How small is "very small"? Is the user turnover really high enough that it's worth investing in a user management infrastructure? If it's a couple-times-a-year thing, maybe the best way to solve this is with a help ticket system answered by you.

If it *is* really important to delegate this ability, how technical is the person who will do it? Could they handle sshing into a server and running `cyradm` from the command line? (Or using it remotely, but I don't think it supports ssl so that's not so secure.)

Another approach would be to have the server authenticate against an LDAP directory, and the company could use any number of typical LDAP-account-management tools. Is the company a Linux shop, or are they Windows-centric? Perhaps they already have an AD server, even.

Failing that, there exists a project called [web-cyradm](http://www.web-cyradm.org/) which might do what you want. I've never used it, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available for ISP type operations - plesk and cpanel being the ones I've seen most frequently. These do make this kind of operation very simple to set up. Both are commercial products - while that means some upfront costs, you should also be getting a support package too though. There are some alternative free products listed [here](http://wiki.debian.org/HostingControlPanels)

OTOH, you might want to have a look at GoSA - this is more geared towards managing an enterprise LDAP directory - so (AFAIK) won't handle all the email and vhost setup for different domains. Unlike plesk and cpanel it is free.

Comment: There are several free alternatives to cPanel and Plesk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels

Comment: awesome, thanks! I love those wikipedia comparison pages. Granted they never quite have the categories I'm interested in, but still a huge time saver.